# Is there a way to output function durations with trace-cmd that is exclusive of nested function durations?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, trace, ftrace

I am tracing a load generator with trace-cmd.  Here is a snippet of output from my trace-cmd report:

```
     loadgen-2682  [003]   105.979473: funcgraph_entry:                   |              select_task_rq_fair() {
     loadgen-2682  [003]   105.979473: funcgraph_entry:                   |                select_idle_sibling() {
     loadgen-2682  [003]   105.979473: funcgraph_entry:        0.071 us   |                  idle_cpu();
     loadgen-2682  [003]   105.979474: funcgraph_entry:        0.111 us   |                  idle_cpu();
     loadgen-2682  [003]   105.979474: funcgraph_entry:        0.056 us   |                  idle_cpu();
     loadgen-2682  [003]   105.979475: funcgraph_entry:        0.056 us   |                  idle_cpu();
     loadgen-2682  [003]   105.979475: funcgraph_exit:         2.324 us   |                }
     loadgen-2682  [003]   105.979476: funcgraph_exit:         2.940 us   |              }
     loadgen-2682  [003]   105.979476: funcgraph_entry:                   |              set_task_cpu() {
     loadgen-2682  [003]   105.979476: funcgraph_entry:                   |                migrate_task_rq_fair() {
     loadgen-2682  [003]   105.979476: funcgraph_entry:        0.080 us   |                  remove_entity_load_avg();
     loadgen-2682  [003]   105.979477: funcgraph_exit:         0.537 us   |                }
     loadgen-2682  [003]   105.979477: funcgraph_entry:        0.042 us   |                set_task_rq_fair();
     loadgen-2682  [003]   105.979478: funcgraph_exit:         1.463 us   |              }
```

The durations of all functions look suspiciously like they are inclusive of time spent in nested function calls.  For example, I believe `select_idle_sibling()`'s duration of 2.324 us is including the .294 us (total) spent inside of the `idle_cpu()` calls.  Similarly, I believe `select_task_rq_fair()` is inclusive of the `select_idle_sibling()` duration.

What I am asking is if there is a way within trace-cmd to turn this off, such that `select_task_rq_fair()` would show its duration exclusive of any functions it has called; i.e. `select_task_rq_fair()` would show a duration of 0.616 us (2.940 us - 2.324 us).  I was unable to locate an answer to this question in [the manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/trace-cmd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having spent some time on this problem, I can say that the answer is almost certainly "no."  If you want to calculate the time spent inside of a function which is exclusive of time spent in any nested functions within, your will need:

- A stack which pushes funcgraph_entries that will have nested calls (i.e., funcgraph_entries which do not have a listed duration) and pops when it sees the entries' corresponding funcgraph_exit calls
- A way to keep track of the durations of nested calls, so that you may subtract their summed durations from the duration listed on your target's funcgraph_exit line

This can be done in a few ways, but a simple class might look something like:

```
class FunctionDuration:
    def __init__(self, function_name):
        name = function_name
        nested_call_duration = 0
        duration = 0
```